# How to open window always on external screen using devilspie2?

Tags: multi-monitor, window

Does anyone know if devilspie2 supports opening a specific window always on the external screen?

I have one Chrome extension window that always opens on the internal one even if Chrome is opened on the external one.

What I found from research is the *geometry option* but was wondering if anyone knows whether there is a specific option to directly address the secondary screen.

**Chrome extension window:**

[image]